# creating links without making new html/php pages?

Tags: php, html

My question is how can I make direct links to the specific news content?

I'd like to make a link where it says Posted: June 1, 2014, 12:24 am and I'd like to make it to to another link where it only has that news article. like juneausmashbros.com/news/congrats-blahblahblah

each news topic is made in php with this code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);


while($row =  $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<article class="content grid_8">';

    $row_date = strtotime($row['date']);
    $the_date = date("F j, Y, g:i a" , $row_date);


    echo '<h1>';
    echo utf8_encode($row['title']);
    echo '</h1>';

    echo '<section>';

    echo '<div class="info_block">';
    echo "Posted: $the_date";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<hr style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: #cccccc 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; HEIGHT: 1px"> ';
    echo '<br>';

    echo nl2br(stripslashes(utf8_encode($row['post'])));
    echo '</section>';
    echo '</article>';

}
echo '<div class="grid_8">';
echo '<b><a href="index.php?page=newsarchive">News Archive</a></b>';
echo '</div>';


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the link as you already described it, if each news topic has a unique title:

> juneausmashbros.com/news/congrats-blahblahblah

However, I would suggest to use the news id in the URL like this:

```
juneausmashbros.com/news?id=12345
```

Then you have to get the id from the URL:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Now you just have to find this news entry in your database and insert its content into the web page.